# Swift Error - Method Does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: swift, overriding, subclass, xctest

I am running into an issue where when I am attempting to override a function it is telling me that there is no method in the superclass.  The subclass is in an XCTest.  When I subclass in the regular project it works perfectly but the XCTest does not work for some reason  Below is the Code

**SuperClass**

```
class BackupServerCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var serverNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var serverDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    func configCell(with server: VeeamBackupServer) {

    }
 }
```

**Subclass** - Located in the XCTest file

```
class MockBackupServerCell : BackupServerCell {
    var configCellGotCalled = false

    override func configCell(with server: VeeamBackupServer) {
        configCellGotCalled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: try cleaning the project and then building and running, *then* run your tests again

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on a Test target, its sometime needed to import your main project.

Let's say your project is named 'MyAwesomeProject', just need to add this line in your test file:

> @testable import MyAwesomeProject

To obtain something like this:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyAwesomeProject

class TestStaticQueries: XCTestCase {
    // Add your test methods here.
}
```

Comment: I do have that at the top of my class.  The weird thing is that autocomplete will put the function correctly when I start to type it. But after I type it then the compiler error occurs.

Comment: @MatthewWandell, hum... the last thing I would suggest you, is to try to add your Test Target as a member of your BackupServerCell class target Membership.

Answer (score 0):

@DDelforge, was partially correct.  I had to add the BackupServerCell class, to the Test Target.  Not sure why this class is different, but hey, it works.

Thank you all

Comment: Adding production code to the test target is a mistake. It indicates that the test target isn't linking correctly against your production target.